# Use sed in docker to replace path

Tags: bash, docker, sed, dockerfile, patch

I know it may be a stupid question ...
I want to do a docker from a docker file. The thing is that I do not have the Command-line completion when I'm going in the docker using docker run -it docker_name /bin/bash.
So I did this https://docs.docker.com/machine/completion/ (still not working) and want to do this https://linuxconfig.org/tab-does-not-automatically-complete-docker-commands-solution

The thing is that I'm not able to replace the few line from the docker file. I wanted to use the command sed like this : `RUN sed -i 's+#if ! shopt -oq posix; then+if ! shopt -oq posix; then+g' /etc/bash.bashrc` but it does not work to replace line containing a path (I'm getting the error sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unterminated `s' command).

I also tryed `RUN sed -i 's+\#  if [ -f \/usr\/share\/bash-compl+  if [ -f \/usr\/share\/bash-compl+g' /etc/bash.bashrc` but got the same result.

What's the good way the use sed in the dockerfile, or what's the good way to update a file in the future docker from the dockerfile ?

------------- EDIT ------------

Sorry I forgot to share my dockerfile.

the first lines are the following :

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --force-yes \
    software-properties-common build-essential wget curl git pkg-config cmake-curses-gui vim nano doxygen libboost-all-dev libeigen3-dev libflann-dev freeglut3-dev libglew-dev
# to get cmake3.0
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --force-yes \
    cmake

RUN apt-get install --yes --force-yes \
    g++ python

# Intall some basic GUI tools
RUN apt-get install --yes --force-yes \
        cmake-qt-gui gnome-terminal
```

I want to edit the file /etc/bash.bashrc in the docker so I did :

```
RUN sed -i 's+#if ! shopt -oq posix; then+if ! shopt -oq posix; then+g' /etc/bash.bashrc #this works
RUN sed -i 's+\#  if [ -f \/usr\/share\/bash-compl+  if [ -f \/usr\/share\/bash-compl+g' /etc/bash.bashrc #this does not work and provide the previous error
```

Comment: Kindly share your Dockerfile if that's possible. If not what base Image are you using?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question to provide it.

Answer (score 3):

`'s+#  if \[ -f /usr/share/bash-compl+  if \[ -f /usr/share/bash-compl+g'` should parse.

You need to escape the square brackets `[` to `\[`.  Square brackets allow grouping characters in sed, so they will not match the literal brackets unless escaped.

You do not need to escape the forward slashes if you continue to use `s+++` rather than `s///`.